# Vim inner tag blocks for Django templates

Tags: django, templates, vim, django-templates

Does a plugin exist which provides these text objects for Django templates? For example, in HTML/XML if I have the following text

```
<p>This is some text.<p>
```

and my  cursor is positioned anywhere inside the tags, I can use `cit` to change the text inside the tags. I'm looking for something similar for Django templates. For example, with the text

```
{% block title %}This is the title{% endblock %}
```

I'd like the same behavior. If nothing exists, any vimscripters out there know if this is possible and willing to give some hints?

Thanks!

Comment: @RandyMorris Cleaning up old questions. Could you post that as an answer? It's the closest I have to a solution.

Comment: Done, and thank you for revisiting old questions.  We need more like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django-template-textobjects plugin (https://github.com/mjbrownie/django-template-textobjects) allows you to achieve this.  It adds a series of text objects (for example db for Django block, df for Django for loop, etc).

For example, cidb would allow you to change the contents of:

```
{% block stylesheets %}My stylesheets here{% endblock %}
```

The plugin depends upon another plugin, vim-textobj-user (https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user), so remember to install that first.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on the official Django documentation.
There is a "Using Vim with Django" section.

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/UsingVimWithDjango

and a *surround* mapping part.

---

Here is an extract :

```
let b:surround_{char2nr("v")} = "{{ \r }}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("{")} = "{{ \r }}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("%")} = "{% \r %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("b")} = "{% block \1block name: \1 %}\r{% endblock \1\1 %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("i")} = "{% if \1condition: \1 %}\r{% endif %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("w")} = "{% with \1with: \1 %}\r{% endwith %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("f")} = "{% for \1for loop: \1 %}\r{% endfor %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("c")} = "{% comment %}\r{% endcomment %}"
```

Put the above in ~/.vim/ftplugin/htmldjango.vim.

Examples in visual mode (select some text first):

- type **Sv** or **S{** for a variable
- type **Sb** for a block
- type **Si** for an if statement
- type **Sw** for a with statement
- type **Sc** for a comment
- type **Sf** for a for statement
- type **S%** for other template tags

PS : another possibility is the use of eclim (vim + eclipse) which supports Django project and template editing http://eclim.org/vim/python/django.html but that's a lot heavier.

Comment: Yes. I've seen this before, but this what I was asking about. Still nice though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to write your own text-object for this. See [textobj-rubyblock](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3382) and [vim-indent-object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) for examples of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Randy! Haven't gotten around to doing this, but if I do, I'll post here.